# Linq query assistance

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity

I have a screen in which the user can select which categories they want to subscribe to. They can select zero to many categories. These get stored in a UserCategory table, which has a userid and a category id.

So, if the user select 2 out of the 8 categories, I write two rows, with the category ids and the userid.

(He is now assigned to TWO categories)

However, if the user returns, and deselects one of the categories, and then adds 2 different categories, he is now assigned to 3 categories...

But I'm unsure of a good way to handle this in linq... Somehow, I need to do something like ... DELETE FROM UserCategories where userId = :UserId and CategoryId NOT IN the int[] of category ids passed in.... And then I need to INSERT INTO UserCategories ... the int[] category ids, but not the ones that already exist.

And I need to do it in Linq, using Entity Framework... Can someone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to remove the user from *all* current categories and re-add to those that are still selected. While you are potentially removing and adding the same information again, it keeps the code simpler and simpler code is easier to maintain.

So you'd read the current information from the database and present that on the form. Then when the user hits "OK" clear current information in the database (keeping the copy in memory of course) and then add it back as though it was the first time through the code.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF - That's certainly an option I am maybe going to use. I can delete from table where UserId = :UserId, and then re-add based on the int[] of Categories. It's pretty easy, and very quick, so I might go that route. Just waiting to see if there's any other ways - because I do store audit data (Date Link was created, andy by whom it was created). Doing this method would delete all audit data.

Comment: @cdotlister - Needing audit data would complicate things. Hmm. Not sure how to proceed in this case.

Comment: I've gone this route... as this is a linking table, and just used to assist the user in a selection, I've decided that in this case, we don't need to audit the table. The user is the only person who can change this. It's a preference. So, done. Thanks.